# Pin Code Screen phone gap android

Tags: android, security, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I've started to write my phonegap android application, and I need to set a feature in my application that shows `enter your pin code` when the application starts. This makes sure no-one who doesn't know the code uses it.

My Questions:

- Can I use the system pin code dialog like in IOS?
- Is there any Phonegap plugin can be included to run this screen?
- How can I make a screen like this in phonegap android?

Comment: You just need a text field and a table of buttons that represent 0-9. This is pretty standard html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would do the job. Works great on iPhone and Android. http://www.html5tutorial.info/html5-contact.php

```
<input type="tel" />
```